# Image proccessing to Show outline using NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am new to android ndk.I have started learning through the image processing example by ruckus and by IBM blog. I am trying to show outline of an image. Here is the code i am using

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class OutlineClass extends Activity{
    private ImageView imageView;
      private Bitmap bitmap;
      private Button button;
      private Bitmap original;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.outline);

          original  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wallace);
          bitmap    = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wallace);
          button    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.obutton);
          imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.oimageView2);
          button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                  ShowOutline();

            }


        });

        }

        private void ShowOutline() {
            Bitmap oBitmap = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Bitmap gBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            showOutlineWithNative(oBitmap,gBitmap );
            imageView.setImageBitmap(gBitmap);

        }

        public native void showOutlineWithNative(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2);
    }
```

And this is the c code i am using for showing out line of the image

```
/*
To show outline
Pixel operation
*/
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_OutlineClass_showOutlineWithNative(JNIEnv
* env, jobject  obj, jobject bitmapedges,jobject bitmapgray)
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo  infogray;
        void*              pixelsgray;
        AndroidBitmapInfo  infoedges;
        void*              pixelsedge;
        int                ret;
        int             y;
        int             x;
        int             sumX,sumY,sum;
        int             i,j;
        int                Gx[3][3];
        int                Gy[3][3];
        uint8_t            *graydata;
        uint8_t            *edgedata;


        LOGI("findEdges running");

        Gx[0][0] = -1;Gx[0][1] = 0;Gx[0][2] = 1;
        Gx[1][0] = -2;Gx[1][1] = 0;Gx[1][2] = 2;
        Gx[2][0] = -1;Gx[2][1] = 0;Gx[2][2] = 1;



        Gy[0][0] = 1;Gy[0][1] = 2;Gy[0][2] = 1;
        Gy[1][0] = 0;Gy[1][1] = 0;Gy[1][2] = 0;
        Gy[2][0] = -1;Gy[2][1] = -2;Gy[2][2] = -1;


        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapedges, &infogray)) < 0) {
            LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
            return;
        }


        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapgray, &infoedges)) < 0) {
            LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
            return;
        }




        if (infogray.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_A_8) {
            LOGE("Bitmap format is not A_8 !");
            return;
        }


        if (infoedges.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_A_8) {
            LOGE("Bitmap format is not A_8 !");
            return;
        }



        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapedges, &pixelsgray)) < 0) {
            LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        }

        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapgray, &pixelsedge)) < 0) {
            LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        }


        // modify pixels with image processing algorithm


        LOGI("time to modify pixels....");

        graydata = (uint8_t *) pixelsgray;
        edgedata = (uint8_t *) pixelsedge;

        for (y=0;y<=infogray.height - 1;y++) {
            for (x=0;x<infogray.width -1;x++) {
                sumX = 0;
                sumY = 0;
                // check boundaries
                if (y==0 || y == infogray.height-1) {
                    sum = 0;
                } else if (x == 0 || x == infogray.width -1) {
                    sum = 0;
                } else {
                    // calc X gradient
                    for (i=-1;i<=1;i++) {
                        for (j=-1;j<=1;j++) {
                            sumX += (int) ( (*(graydata + x + i + (y + j)
    * infogray.stride)) * Gx[i+1][j+1]);
                        }
                    }

                    // calc Y gradient
                    for (i=-1;i<=1;i++) {
                        for (j=-1;j<=1;j++) {
                            sumY += (int) ( (*(graydata + x + i + (y + j)
    * infogray.stride)) * Gy[i+1][j+1]);
                        }
                    }

                    sum = abs(sumX) + abs(sumY);

                }

                if (sum>255) sum = 255;
                if (sum<0) sum = 0;

                *(edgedata + x + y*infogray.width) = 255 - (uint8_t) sum;



            }
        }

        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapgray);
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapedges);

}
```

The result i am getting is the same image with no changes...
I know the sebel algorithm used to detect the outline but i am not getting  how programatically it is detecting edges   please let me know what is wrong in the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give the links of these blogs?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there are several issues here.

For starters, in your NDK Code, you check that the input bitmaps are encoded as Alpha_8 images (that is, grayscale images):

```
if (infogray.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_A_8) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not A_8 !");
        return;
}


if (infoedges.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_A_8) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not A_8 !");
        return;
}
```

When you create the bitmaps, you pass the `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` to the `copy` function. I suspect this causes these checks to fail, and thus the function returns before having processed the image. You should create your bitmaps using `copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, true)`

It also seems to me that you try to display the wrong bitmap at the end of the process: you pass the bitmaps to `showOutlineWithNative` in the wrong order. The bitmap you want to display is  the `bitmapedges` argument of the native function, and here you're about to display the input, grayscale image.

To sum it up, it seems to me like the right piece of code for `ShowOutline` would be:

```
private void ShowOutline() {
        // grayscale version of the original bitmap:
        Bitmap gray = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, true);
        // receiver bitmap for the Sobel detector:
        Bitmap output = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, true);

        showOutlineWithNative(output, gray);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(output);

}
```

Keep me posted on your progress!

Comment: Hey i tried with what you suggested but this time image is not being displayed.

Comment: Hey i tried with what you suggested but this time image is not being displayed.here is the code i used [click here](http://pastebin.com/rYbbqpxS) and the order is `private void ShowOutline() {
   Bitmap oBitmap = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, true);
   Bitmap gBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, true);
   
   showOutlineWithNative(gBitmap,oBitmap );
   System.out.println("Config back : "+gBitmap.getConfig());
      imageView.setImageBitmap(gBitmap);
   
  }

  public native void showOutlineWithNative(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2);
 }
`

Comment: What do you mean by "not being displayed"? Do you have a fully black image?
If so, an explanation may be that the bitmap returned by your native function is not contrasted enough: if the values of the Sobel filter are for example very low, you would not be able to see the edges.
Also, what does the `System.out.println("Config back : "+gBitmap.getConfig());` call return?

Comment: ya i think i am getting fully black image thats y i am not able to see the image.`System.out.println("Config back : "+gBitmap.getConfig());`this you can ignore i was trying to debug.Now how can i make this thing working?

Comment: If i were you, i would try putting debug traces everywhere in the double loop where the pixels are modified, to see what are the values of `sumX` and `sumY` as well as the final value assigned to the pixel. If you see that these values change and are not absurd, we'll be able to isolate whether the problem comes from the C part or the Java part.

Comment: Thanks, i do as suggested and let you know.